# How to create a toggle button using Bootstrap Toggle plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code to create a toggle button

```
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
```

I'm using these libraries from http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/#usage,

```
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

But it just shows up as a plain checkbox. How do I make it look fancy?

Here is a link to what I've got so far - http://jsbin.com/bocawucili/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it comes down to the ORDER of your tags, jQuery ALWAYS needs to be BEFORE anything that requires it.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Works like a charm :)